# C# AStar problems, won't do it correctly

Tags: c#, xna, path-finding, a-star

I am currently working on A* pathfinding, but I am having some problems.
It does the wrong path before taking the best path to the end.
What am I doing wrong?

Source code: http://basic.apayostudios.com/AStar.zip

Online:

Game.cs http://pastie.org/1656955

Node.cs http://pastie.org/1656956

Enums:

```
public enum NodeType
{
    None,
    Solid,
    Start,
    End
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Debug it. Watch the execution of the program in the debugger right up to the point where it chooses the *first* incorrect move. Then figure out why it did that. If you have the algorithm correct then odds are good your heuristic is wrong. If the heuristic is right then odds are good you have the algorithm wrong.  What if you replace it with a zero heuristic, thereby giving you Dijkstra's Algorithm? Does it still give the wrong answer?  Then it is probably some problem with the algorithm, not the heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my A-star path finder, it works and you're free to use it for learning and comparing your solution against it, rip me off if you like. But there are dependencies that are missing from this code and I'm using fixed-point arithmetic. This won't build without some changes. This code is relatively high level and should be easy enough to reverse engineer.

```
public class AgentPathfinder
{
    class SolutionComparer : IComparer<Solution>
    {
        public int Compare(Solution x, Solution y)
        {
            return x.Cost.CompareTo(y.Cost);
        }
    }

    class Solution 
    {
        public List<FixedVector> Path { get; private set; }

        public FixedVector LastPosition { get { return Path[Path.Count - 1]; } }

        public Fixed32 Heuristic { get; set; }
        public Fixed32 Cost { get; set; }

        public Solution(FixedVector position, Fixed32 heuristic)
        {
            Path = new List<FixedVector>(2) { position };
            Heuristic = heuristic;
            Cost = Path.Count + heuristic;
        }

        public Solution(FixedVector position
            , Fixed32 heuristic
            , List<FixedVector> path)
        {
            Path = new List<FixedVector>(path) { position };
            Heuristic = heuristic;
            Cost = Path.Count + heuristic;
        }
    }

    // TODO: replace with pathable terrain data
    public Map Map { get; set; }

    public FixedVector Position { get; set; }
    public FixedVector Destination { get; set; }

    public List<FixedVector> Path { get; set; }

    public void Compute()
    {
        var visited = new bool[(int)Map.Size.Width, (int)Map.Size.Height];

        var pq = new PriorityQueue<Solution>(new SolutionComparer());

        var bestFit = new Solution(new FixedVector((int)(Position.X + 0.5)
            , (int)(Position.Y + 0.5))
            , (Destination - Position).Length
            );

        pq.Enqueue(bestFit);

        while (pq.Count > 0)
        {
            var path = pq.Dequeue(); // optimal, thus far
            if (path.Heuristic < bestFit.Heuristic) // best approximation?
            {
                // if we starve all other paths we
                // fallback to this, which should be the best
                // approximation for reaching the goal
                bestFit = path;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < FixedVector.Adjacent8.Length; i++)
            {
                var u = path.LastPosition + FixedVector.Adjacent8[i];
                if (Map.Size.Contains(u))
                {
                    if (Map.IsPathable(u))
                    {
                        if (!visited[(int)u.X, (int)u.Y])
                        {
                            // heuristic (straight-line distance to the goal)
                            var h = (Destination - u).Length; 
                            var solution = new Solution(u, h, path.Path);
                            if (h < 1)
                            {
                                Path = solution.Path;
                                return; // OK, done
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // keep looking
                                pq.Enqueue(solution);
                            }
                            visited[(int)u.X, (int)u.Y] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Path = bestFit.Path;
    }
}
```